# VLOOKUP to bring data from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table containing a some football data, such as Country, League, Teams, Standing table information, such as total matches played, wins, draws, losses, goals scored and conceded, and so on.
[Here's a file download link](https://transferxl.com/08jdrB08mJ4DYR)

It contains two sheets.
First sheet is STANDINGS_EXTENDED:

[image]

I need to fill these 3 tables with the data contained in another STANDINGS worksheet.

Here's a screenshot of the STANDINGS sheet:

[image]

My aim is that once I fill LeagueId and Group Id (which is optional) fields then inside all three tables will be produced the data as in this sample.

I wonder if it is possible to achieve this without VBA. But i have no clue on where to start from. I tried is several different ways, but i get only first result from STANDINGS worksheet for any league i enter.

Looking forward to your help.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
So far I could get the count of rows related to Overall, Home and Away using these formulas:

```
=COUNTIFS(STANDINGS!E:E;STANDINGS_EXTENDED!E1;STANDINGS!F:F;"StandingsOverall")

=COUNTIFS(STANDINGS!E:E;STANDINGS_EXTENDED!$E$1;STANDINGS!F:F;"StandingsHome")

=COUNTIFS(STANDINGS!E:E;STANDINGS_EXTENDED!$E$1;STANDINGS!F:F;"StandingsAway")
```

Also, what I can get is the first row of these results using this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($E$1;STANDINGS!$E:$V;4;FALSE)
```

What I need to figure out is how to modify above formulas so that I fill tables with remaining rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this you need a formula in every single field of your 3 tables that link it to data on the *Standings* tab. That would be 13 x 3 x 20 formulas. Therefore one would try to create formulas that can be copied, in the best case less than 13 original ones, but definitely one formula for each field.

Each formula would look for a unique identifier in the *Standings* list. I can't see any unique identifiers there but you might create them by concatenation, such as "League" + "Country" + "Position". The more detail you need the larger the formula. The key is: without a unique identifier for each row you can't retrieve data. But once a row has been identified you can get the value from any of its columns.

If your tables sometimes have 12 rows, sometimes 20, and sometimes 25 you must provide space for the possible maximum and then design your formulas to return a blank if there is nothing to display.

In conclusion, the core of your system is in the *Standings* table. It must be set up so that data can be retrieved from it. Ideally, your selection on the *Standings Extended* sheet would generate a concatenated unique identifier for a list to which you can add the fixed number in the `Pos` column to identify individual rows in the *Standing* table. As long as you can't identify rows no data can be retrieved.

Using VBA gives you more flexibility but doesn't relieve you of the task to create uniquely identifiable rows.